# If $f : B(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, and $\forall\ |z_n|\rightarrow 1$, {$f(z_n)$} is not bounded, then $f$ has at least one root

Tags: complex-analysis

Title says all. I submitted my attempt at answering it. It would be interesting to see if anywone had a different idea though!

Comment: Please make the **body** of your questions self-contained. The title should be a title.

Comment: Then I should copy the title in the body? The title should say less?

Comment: Yes. Not necessarily. The body of the question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ has no zero in $B(0,1)$ (which I presume is your notation for the open unit disk).  Let $T(0,r)$ be the positively oriented circle $|z|=r$.  Consider the line segment $L$ from $0$ to $f(1/2)$.  For each $r \in (1/2, 1)$, the winding number of $f(T(0,r))$ about $0$ is $0$, while the winding number about $f(1/2)$ is at least $1$.  Therefore $f(T(0,r))$ must intersect the line segment $L$.  For $n \ge 3$ take $z_n \in T(0, 1-1/n)$ such that $f(z_n) \in L$.  Then $|z_n| \to 1$ but $|f(z_n)| \le |f(1/2)|$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ doesn't have any roots in $\Delta=B(0,1)$. Then $g=1/f$ is well defined and holomorphic in $\Delta$.

Let's see that $\bar{g} : \bar{\Delta} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined as

$g(z) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & |z| = 1 \\
      g(z) & |z|<1  
   \end{cases} 
$ is continuous in $\bar{\Delta}$.

Let $|z_n| \rightarrow 1$. Let $M>0$. Suppose that $\exists$ infinite $n_k$ such that $|f(z_{n_k})| \leq M$. Then $z_{n_k}$ contradicts the hypothesis, absurd.

Then $|f(z_n)|> M\ \forall\ n \geq\ n_0$, for certain $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$

Then $f(z_n)\rightarrow \infty$, and $g(z_n) \rightarrow 0$.

We can conclude that $\bar{g}$ is continuous in $\bar{\Delta}$, and of course is holomorphic in $\Delta$. Then, by the maximum modulus principle, $\bar{g}$ attaches its maximum in the border, i.e., zero. Then $\bar{g} \equiv 0$. Then $g \equiv 0$, Absurd!

Comment: It would be best if you included your attempt as part of your original post.

Comment: but my attempt is an answer, I'm not asking anything.

Comment: @Senor Billy...I think you are trying to verify your answer though, still it has to be the part of your OP.

Comment: Mhmm, no, I'm not trying that. Q&A is an option when you post a question, right? I'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

The hypotheses are equivalent to saying $f$ is analytic in $B(0,1)$ and $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to 1^-.$ But there is no such function. Suppose otherwise. Then $f$ has only finitely many zeros $z_1,\dots, z_n$ in $B(0,1),$ counting mulitplicity. Define $g(z) = f(z)/[(z-z_1)\cdots (z-z_n)].$ Then $g$ is nonzero and analytic in $B(0,1),$ and it has the same property. It follows that $1/g$ is analytic and nonzero in $B(0,1),$ and satisfies $|1/g(z)|\to 0$ as $|z| \to 1^-.$ This contradicts the maximum modulus theorem. Therefore such an $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: Why is that equivalent? I don't say that $|f(z)|$ converges uniformely to $\infty$

Comment: @SeñorBilly  Suppose $|f(z)|$ does not go to $\infty$ as $|z|\to 1^-.$ Then there exists $M$ such that for every $r\in (0,1),$ there exists $z$ with $r<|z|<1,$ such that $|f(z)| \le M.$ From this you can get a sequence $z_n$ in the disc such that $|z_n|\to 1^-$ and $|f(z_n)|\le M$ for all $n.$ That violates the assumption on $f.$